# How to get a value of a custom Schemas in Google Apps Scriptw

Tags: google-apps-script

/*I'm trying to get the custom schemas I have on my GSuite Directory but it shows undefined*/

```
function listAllUsers() {
  var pageToken, page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'amaro.com',
      orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
       Logger.log('%s - %s - %s - %s - %s', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail, user.relations, user.organizations, user.customSchemas);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Comment: what is undefined? what's the full error log?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **projection: 'full',**

```
  orderBy: 'givenName',
  maxResults: 500,
  projection: 'full',
```

it will bring all your custom schemas